# Java - cadena String contiene caracteres y números

Tags: java, substring

estoy tratando de averiguar so una cadena de caracteres contiene un patrón de la siguiente forma:

- tiene letras en mayúscula al principio
- tiene 4 dígitos al final.

Mediante regex, he visto que podría partir de algo así:

```
dorsal.matches("^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]+$")
```

Esto no es exactamente lo que busco porque aquí se comprueba si hay letras en mayúsculas y números.

La otra forma es separando el string:

```
// revisar que las 4 últimas posiciones son números
int dorsalNumbers = dorsal.substring(dorsal.length()-4, dorsal.length());
dorsalNumbers.matches("[0-9]+");

// revisar que el resto del string son letras mayúsculas
String dorsalLetters = dorsal.substring(0, dorsal.length()-4);
dorsalLetters.matches("[A-Z]+");
```

Tiene sentido hacerlo de esta forma?

Cómo lo haríais?
Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria asi..

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    public class Regex{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    String cadena="HolaMundo12aZ";
             Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z].*[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$.*");
         Matcher mat = pat.matcher(cadena);                                                                           
         if (mat.matches()) {
             System.out.println("SI");
         } else {
             System.out.println("NO");                                                                                
         }
    
    }}
```